# ValueError-data-must-be-1-dimensional

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array, valueerror

```
def make_predictions(data, predictors):
    train = data[data['date'] <= '2021-01-01']
    test = data[data['date'] > '2021-01-01']
    rf.fit(train[predictors], train['target'])
    preds = rf.predict(test[predictors])
    probs = rf.predict_proba(test[predictors])
    combined = pd.DataFrame(dict(actual=test['target'], prediction=preds, chanceWinning=probs), index=test.index)
    precision = precision_score(test['target'], preds)
    return combined, precision
```

`probs.dtype`
`dtype('float64')`

`preds.dtype` 
`dtype('int32')`

`probs`
`array([0.08724087, 0.10874464, 0.63047835, ..., 0.19235231, 0.01306818, 0.89918252])`

`preds`
`array([0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 1])`

`probs.shape`
`(1966,)`

`preds.shape`
`(1966,)`

When i try:

```
combined = pd.DataFrame(dict(actual=test['target'], prediction=preds), index=test.index)
```

instead of:

```
combined = pd.DataFrame(dict(actual=test['target'], prediction=preds, chanceWinning=probs), index=test.index)
```

it works just fine.

I get the same error with:

```
combined = pd.DataFrame(dict(actual=test['target'], chanceWinning=probs), index=test.index)
```

I can't really convert `probs` into an integer, because it represents percentages.
Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: What are the `shape`s of `probs` and `preds`?

Comment: both are `(1966,)`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

```
def make_predictions(data, predictors):
    train = data[data['date'] <= '2021-01-01']
    test = data[data['date'] > '2021-01-01']
    rf.fit(train[predictors], train['target'])
    preds = rf.predict(test[predictors])
    probs = rf.predict_proba(test[predictors])
    probs = np.split(probs, 2, axis=1)
    probs = probs[1].flatten()
    combined = pd.DataFrame(dict(actual=test['target'], prediction=preds, chanceWinning=probs), index=test.index)
    precision = precision_score(test['target'], preds)
    return combined, precision
```

Comment: What was the actual fix?  Looks like `.flatten()` ?